# Two different HashMap returning the same hashCode

Tags: java, hashmap, hashcode

I have two different sets of HashMap (**{u=0, h=3}** and **{t=3, i=0}**), and it is returning the **same hashCode** (**224**). I don't understand this, hashCode needs to be different for different objects, and here the HashMap contains different sets of key and value pairs, but it still returns the same hashCode. **Can someone please explain how this works?**

trying to get the hashcode of the hashmap in java

Comment: "hashCode needs to be different for different objects". That's not true. It just has to be the same for equal objects.

Comment: There’s an infinite number of possible maps. How could you expect to get a distinct 32 bit number for each of them?

Answer (score 3):

You are perhaps misunderstanding the point of the `hashCode()` method.

`hashCode()` is a method that works in tandem with `equals(Object)`:

- `equals(Object)` is for telling you if two objects are definitely equal
- `hashCode()` if for telling you if two objects are definitely *not* equal:

  - Two objects with different `hashCode()` values are definitely not equal
  - Two objects with the same `hashCode()` values may be equal

This might sound a bit odd: it's kinda vague to know if things aren't equal: you have to do something more to determine if they *are* equal (that is, use the `equals(Object)` method).

What's the point of having two methods, one vague, one precise, to determine equality?

Let's say you've got 1000 objects, and you want to know which ones are equal: armed only with the `equals` method, you've got to do a pairwise comparison between all of them, so, roughly 500000 comparisons.

Enter `hashCode()`: you can use the hash of each object to put them into buckets: there's no point in checking if objects with different hash codes are `equals`, because they won't be (assuming correct implementation of `hashCode()`). You only have to do 1000 bucket operations.

Maybe you end up with only one item in each bucket; maybe you end up with 5 things in one bucket; now, you only have to do 12 pairwise comparisons to find which ones are equal.

`hashCode()` is really an ugly internal implementation detail: it is only present in order to support `HashMap`, `HashTable` etc (as described in the Javadoc).

You shouldn't ever really care about or use its value. All equal objects will have the same value, but some unequal objects will also have the same value. `hashCode()` is a source of bugs because it needs to be implemented consistently with `equals(Object)`, but there is no language-level support to ensure that consistency. In an ideal world, it wouldn't be visible to us.

Don't expect it to have any properties beyond what it's designed for.

Answer (score 1):

As [Commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77020612/two-different-hashmap-returning-the-same-hashcode#comment135777759_77020612), your statement:

> hashCode needs to be different for different objects

is incorrect.

A [hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) takes an input, and returns a value derived from the input. The returned value is consistent. The same input always returns the same hash value.

However, two inputs *can* indeed coincidentally return the same hash value. This is known as a *collision*. One aspect of a good hash function is that collisions are unlikely. But collisions are always possible. Inputs are infinite but hash values are finite; so obviously collisions *must* be possible.

Let's test your assertion your two example maps result in the same hash value.

```java
Map < String, Integer > mapX =
        new HashMap <> (
                Map.of (
                        "u" , 0 ,
                        "h" , 3
                )
        );

Map < String, Integer > mapY =
        new HashMap <> (
                Map.of (
                        "t" , 3 ,
                        "i" , 0
                )
        );

Map < String, Integer > mapZ =
        new HashMap <> (
                Map.of (
                        "Alphabet" , 7 ,
                        "Street" , 42
                )
        );

int hashX = mapX.hashCode ( );
int hashY = mapY.hashCode ( );
int hashZ = mapZ.hashCode ( );
```

Dump to console.

```java
System.out.println ( "mapX = " + mapX );
System.out.println ( "mapY = " + mapY );
System.out.println ( "mapZ = " + mapZ );

System.out.println ( "hashX = " + hashX );
System.out.println ( "hashY = " + hashY );
System.out.println ( "hashZ = " + hashZ );
```

When run:

```
mapX = {h=3, u=0}
mapY = {t=3, i=0}
mapZ = {Alphabet=7, Street=42}
hashX = 224
hashY = 224
hashZ = 177047197
```

Indeed, both your maps result in the same value returned from `hashCode`: 224. Our third map results in a different hash value: 177,047,197.

If you want to know exactly why those particular inputs result in the same hash value, study the [source code from OpenJDK](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/HashMap.java).

Comment: There is no need to study the source code. Maps have a [precisely specified contract](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#hashCode()) which should not surprise, as for example, `Map.of ("u" , 0 , "h" , 3).equals(new HashMap<>(Map.of ("u" , 0 , "h" , 3)))` and therefore, `Map.of ("u" , 0 , "h" , 3).hashCode() == new HashMap<>( Map.of ("u" , 0 , "h" , 3)).hashCode()` must be `true`, which can only work if those different implementation classes adhere to a common contract.

Comment: @Holger The code in this Question is not about different implementations of `Map`, only the `HashMap` implementation. And, the code in this Question is not about adding entries in a different order. This Question asks why two `HashMap` objects with *completely different keys* would produce the same hash result. So, I do not understand the point of your Comment. To understand why those particular inputs generate the same numerical result, one must indeed examine the mathematics of the particular hash function. That function is found in the source code of OpenJDK.

Comment: My comment is not about the order of elements either. Don’t know where you get that from. My comment is about the fact that the algorithm is *precisely specified for **all** maps*. You don’t have to dig into implementation details. You can read the specification. That was my point. I even linked the specification. And I consider it helpful to all future readers (and the OP) to mention that this is not an implementation detail but a well specified behavior.